# How can you filter on details of an individual process in New Relic server?

Tags: java, newrelic, dspace

New Relic server comes with a "processes" view on resources consumed per process. However, it bundles processes with the same name together.

In this particular case, see attached screenshot, there are 5 java instances running, and I want to know which one causes trouble. Is there any way to view/filter on the args of a specific java (or any other) process, and to see a view where it isn't bundled together?

I'm on the free New Relic, so this might be a feature of the commercial product I don't know of.

If you can see this in New Relic APM instead of New Relic server, that would be great as well, but I also couldn't find it there.

[image: New Relic Server process overview]

Comment: Two things come to mind, but hope there's an easier solution: instrument each java process with a separate NR agent, so it shows up as different apps in APM OR run each java process under a different user, because NR server automatically splits on processes.

Comment: Here is another clue but I haven't figured it out yet: https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/monitoring-java-processes-separately-by-name/5485/5 There it states that you can pass a parameter through the command line "-Dnewrelic.config.app_name=MY_APPLICATION" to have it show up as a separate application. The problem is that for all jobs with the dspace command line launcher (/bin/dspace) there is only a single java opts config. Ideally, I want to have filter media, subscription mailer etc all show up separately.